# .htaccess remove "//" from url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, uri

Google has found some urls on my webpage with "//" in the url, I want all the pages that has found to redirect to the URLs with just 1 "/".

For Example:

```
https://example.com/kurzy/dero// to https://example.com/kurzy/dero/
https://example.com/kurzy//dero/ to https://example.com/kurzy/dero/
```

I tried that by using htaccess, but it does not work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)//(.*) /$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Can you please help? Thx

Comment: Multiple slashes have already been reduced in the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (so your pattern `^(.*)//(.*)` never matches). See my solution in the linked _duplicate_ question. "Google has found some urls on my webpage" - You still need to "fix" these URLs. The redirect alone is not a solution.